# How can I separate gate to body cap from gate to source cap of a MOSFET?

Tags: mosfet, capacitance, modeling

I am extracting CV parameters of MOSFET Level 1 Model.
I used 2N7000 MOSFET for a measurement.
The body pin is attached to the source pin, and I would like to know how I can separate Cgb values from Cgs.

I finished measuring Cgs and Cgd already.